# Deploying file to WebLogic - Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I received this error on deploying the file to WebLogic.

Should I make any alteration to the **Weblogic.xml** file?

> Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references for "ServletContext@8793091[app:casman-jsf-3 module:casman-jsf-3.5-SNAPSHOT.war path: spec-version:2.5]", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: jstl, Specification-Version: 1.1, exact-match: true], [Extension-Name: jsf-myfaces, Specification-Version: 1.1, exact-match: true]

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, I had to take the following steps (I am developing using Eclipse and deploying to Weblogic 10.3.5):

1. REMOVE weblogic.xml from the /WebContent/WEB-INF/ directory
2. Add needed jars to your lib directory (/WEB-INF/lib/) including JSTL.jar
3. Add project libraries to your Deployment Descriptor
4. Install EAR or WAR to Weblogic

This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

the error is because some library referenced in the Weblogic.xml is not being accessed during deployment.

try to call all the referencing libraries through run (Windows OS). Like if you have some reference to a library called \systemlib\alllibs\lib1.jar, then go to run and try calling in the library file or see manually if you can access the file in the server.

If the file is present then for unix/linux server, check if there are no access rights issue on the system. like if the library was placed by the root user and the weblogic user(Application server) does not have rights to read or write on the library folder. Remove any such issues.

Lastly, since the error specifically says JSTL, therefore check if the JRE version and JSTL version are in sync.

If still the error is not resolved, then please share the weblogic.xml also

Comment: Did this solve the problem? I have the same symptoms after building a new weblogic domain on a new machine. No artefacts including the weblogic.xml file have changed.

Comment: The user has not responded with an answer

Comment: In my case, the answer was to remove my weblogic.xml file and not have one.

Comment: I had this issue and this did not resolve the problem for me.  I am using JSTL so I can't remove the weblogic.xml.  I think the issue is that I am developing on a different version of weblogic than what I am deploying to, and the deployment can't find the system libraries.  I will post a solution once I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Do a deep search of "jsf" in your wlServer\common\deployable-libraries folder . 
Find the library corresponding to that extension and install it into your server. 
Re-deploye the application

## It worked for me